# Query to get data from array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a schema like below:

```
{
topics: [
    {
        topicName: String,
        quesList: [
            {
                quesListName: String,
                by: String,
                questions: [
                    {
                        id: Number,
                        question: String
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to get the quesList array,if the topicName is same as the topic which i send from client side.

Below is my query:

```
exports.query = function(req, res) {
        QuestionList.find(topics.req.query, function(err, questionList) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            return res.status(200).json(fnData(questionList));
        });
    }
```

Comment: than whats the error is? can you post!

Comment: I am not getting the data

Comment: What is `topics.req.query` value and where is the implementation of `fnData() function`?

Comment: topics.req.query value is angular here